# Get the child properties from WindowsFormsHost

Tags: wpf, windowsformshost

I have added a control to a WPF project like this

```
Dim HTMLEditor As New HTMLEditControl
With HTMLEditor
.Name = "EmailSend_Editor"
.EnableInlineSpelling = True
End With

Dim WinHost As New WindowsFormsHost
With WinHost
.Name = "WinHost"
.Child = HTMLEditor
End With
Grid.SetRow(WinHost, 5)
EmailSend_Grid.Children.Add(WinHost)
```

and it displays OK - now the problem is when I want to access the properties of the control. I have tried...

```
Dim WinHost As WindowsFormsHost = EmailSend_Grid.FindName("WinHost")
Dim HTMLEditor As HTMLEditControl = WinHost.Child
```

But it throws 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object' - I have never used WindowsFormsHost before and examples are thin on the ground. Any pointers would be appreciated.

Comment: It seems that `FindName("WinHost")` returns null. Why don't you just keep the original reference to the WindowsFormsHost control in the `WinHost` variable, i.e. make `WinHost` a class member?

Comment: Hi Clemens - it's fine with WinHost - it baulks at Winhost.Child

Comment: When the exception is thrown at `Winhost.Child` then WinHost is null. Besides that, you can as well keep the `HTMLEditor` reference as class member.

Comment: Can you explain your original answer a bit more?

Comment: You have a local variable HTMLEditor. Turn it into a field of the class in which you have that code (e.g. MainWindow), so that you can access the referenced HTMLEditControl from anywhere in that class.

Comment: You mean add it manually to the xaml? That might need a major rewrite as all the other grids are entered dynamically from code behind.

Comment: No, that is not what I mean. You know that MainWindow is a class and that you can add members to a class, like fields, properties and methods?

Comment: Sorry - I was confused about MainWindow - I just added 'Private WinHost As WindowsFormsHost' just underneath the class of the page this is using and everything works. If you want to add that as an answer, I can mark it up. Thank you.

Comment: But why the WindowsFormsHost and not directly the HTMLEditControl??

Comment: Because it's the only half decent HTML editor and it's made for WinForms

Comment: That was not the question. I asked why you would not keep a reference to the HTMLEditControl instead of a reference to the WindowsFormsHost? A class member like `Private HTMLEditor as HTMLEditControl;`

Comment: As far as I know, the control cannot be accessed directly like WPF controls and has to be derived as a child of WindowsFormsHost.

Comment: That sounds wrong. Try it out.

Comment: Yup, did try that initially.

Comment: That does not seem to make sense. When you create the control like `Dim HTMLEditor As New HTMLEditControl` you can obviously also save the value of that variable in a field for later access.